# How do I narrow a type based on a provided property in this TypeScript class?

Tags: typescript

For context, I'm creating a typed API wrapper for IndexedDB.

```js
// Definitions
export interface Config<T> {
  name: string;
  keyPath: keyof T;
}

class Store<T> {
  readonly config: Config<T>;

  constructor(config: Config<T>) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  // The parameter `key` is in question
  get(key: T[this["config"]["keyPath"]]) {}
}
```

I have a TypeScript class `Store<T>` that represents a store with a `keyPath` property defined inside of the `Config<T>` interface. The value of `keyPath` is provided via the constructor. `keyPath` specifies the IndexedDB `keyPath` to use for objects of type `T` stored in the store.

```js
// Using the definitions
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  verified: boolean;
}

const store = new Store<Person>({
  name: "people",
  keyPath: "name",
  indices: [],
});

store.get(false); // Should be marked incorrect but isn't; `verified` property isn't the `keyPath`, so we shouldn't be able to input a boolean
// The observed parameter type is `string | number | boolean`
// It should actually be just `string` since that's the type of the `keyPath` in `Person`
```

I want to somehow obtain the type of `T[this['config']['keyPath']]` based on whatever's provided in the constructor. For example, if the `keyPath` is `"id"` and `T["id"]` is a `string`, then `T[this['config']['keyPath']]` should be a `string` and nothing else.

However, TypeScript seems to infer a union of all the property types of `T` instead of the correct type based on the provided `keyPath`.

I think the main problem is that `T[this['config']['keyPath']]` is equivalent to `T[keyof T]` since `keyPath` is defined as `keyof T`. This creates a union of all property types of `T`, but I just want the type of `keyPath` as it's defined in `T`, which should be just one type.

How do I go about narrowing the type of `T[this['config']['keyPath']]` to reflect the type of `keyPath` in `T` instead of a union of all the property types?